# How to add a new target in Oracle Enterprise Manager 12 C

Tags: oracle, oracle-enterprise-manager

I just installed Oracle Enterprise Manager 12 C Grid Control from a ready made image that Oracle provides and now I am trying to add targets to it (monitoring targets i mean).

It might be a stupid question but how can such a thing be done ? I don't seem to find any tutorials on this and the Oracle docs are not that clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well this task i am afraid it can not be described here, i mean it could but is to much to write and i will not re-invent the wheel.:)
 So i recommend you follow this article [How to add a new target on OEM](http://www.aodba.com/main_articles_single.php?art=26&page=oem) , i wrote this article with this purpose(help guys like you ! kkkkk ).
 i might get a down vote for my short answer ! but for those intrested  -- fell free to read the article !! And thare a lot's of them on Oracle Enterprise Manager 12 C .

Comment: oooo, that was fast. Thx for the answer, i will look into that article.

Comment: No problem , i hope you found your answer !

Comment: Hy, your article was of great help, it did answered my question. And the rest of the articles are great. thank you

Comment: The Oracle docs aren't too difficult to follow if you read them.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/install_agent.htm#EMBSC181 has screenshots and goes through everything in detail.

Comment: I don't argue with that! is just those articles i wrote are specific for a task and they cover only what is needed.

Comment: Still i don't think me helping somebody - made me deserve a -1 vote !